# Getting Data in Power BI from Oracle Apex application backend tables

Tags: oracle-apex, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I was wondering if it is possible to connect the Oracle Apex's data tables in Microsoft Power BI.

Please note that these tables are the ones used in backend of web applications developed and hosted on Oracle Apex website/cloud https://apex.oracle.com (=NOT on-premises).

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not provide database connection information for the database used for https://apex.oracle.com. You can create REST APIs exposing information in the tables and use that information.

[image: Screenshot of RESTful Services]

Comment: Thanks for giving a hint. I'll do some research for the complete method on how to actually achieve this. Once done, i'll update the status here as well as mark this as answer :)